# Javascript calling setter from getter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to call the setter from the getter to initialize default values without repeating the setting logic.

I did come up with a solution that works using getOwnPropertyDescriptor:

```js
var o = {
  set p(val) {
    // setting logic
    alert(val);
    this.pval = val;
  },
  get p() {
    if (!this.pval) {
      const psetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'p').set.bind(this);
      psetter(10); // default to 10
    }
    return this.pval;
  }
}

alert(o.p);
```

However this seems quite convoluted .. is there a simpler way ?

Comment: Why not just return the default value?

Comment: because there is a logic to setting (in this case I used an alert stub) that I need to be called even for the default value

Comment: Any particular reason you're using an object literal instead of a class?

Comment: Tibrogargan will things be different for a class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you can simplify your getter from this:

```
   get p() {
    if (!this.pval) {
      const psetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'p').set.bind(this);
      psetter(10); // default to 10
    }
    return this.pval;
  }
```

to this:

```
   get p() {
    if (!this.pval) {
        this.p = 10;        // trigger setter to set default val
    }
    return this.pval;
  }
```

---

If the default value does not have to be computed by the setter and can be known at object initialization time, then it would be even simpler to just initialize the `pval` property to the appropriate default value when you first create the object, either at declaration time (if it's a static object) or in a constructor if you used either a factory function or a class.  Then, you don't have to call the setter from the getter because the default value is already set.  This alternative way of assuring the default value is initialized would look like this:

```
var o = {
  set p(val) {
    // setting logic
    this.pval = val;
  },
  get p() {
    return this.pval;
  },
  pval: 10           // initialize default value
}
```

---

P.S. if `0` is a legal value for `p`, then you will want to change `if (this.pval)` to `if (this.pval === undefined)`.

Comment: @kofifus - The last code block, initializes `pval` at object definition time so the getter does not need to set `pval`.  Only the setter needs to set `pval` in this scenario.

Comment: @kofifus - The second code block assigns to `p` which WILL trigger the setter for `p`.

Comment: I need to setter to be called whenever that value is set, so your second code does not answer the question. Otherwise I will accept it

Comment: I would advise also to change the test to `if (this.pval === undefined)`, or you'll get a surprise while setting `pval` to `0`

Comment: @kofifus - I didn't change your setter at all.  Leave it as it was.  I just modified the getter.  In my first example (the first two code blocks), I set `p`to the default value (which triggers the setter to be called which will then set `pval`).  In my second example (the last code block), I just set a default value from the beginning so the getter doesn't need to set anything - it can just be a getter.

Comment: @RaphaMex - That was the OP's `if` statement.  I have no idea whether `if (this.pval)` or `if (this.pval === undefined)` is more correct since there was nothing in the question about that.  Perhaps `0` is not a legal value for that propery so `if (this.pval)` is a shortcut.  We have no way of knowing.  I will add a note to my answer about that.

Comment: @kofifus - Perhaps you don't realize that you don't have to manually call the setter.  If you just assign to `p`, that will trigger the setter to run.  That is the whole point of the setter in the first place and it works just fine from your own code as it does from client code using the object.

Comment: no, if you add alert to the setter it does not get called in your second code https://jsfiddle.net/twn9o1ou/

Comment: @kofifus - You don't understand the point of that second code example.  The default value is ALREADY set (at object initialization time) so you don't need to set it in the getter.  If you don't want to do it that way, then use the first option I showed.  I offered you a choice.  Both will work just fine.  This was a DIFFERENT way to solve the problem than you asked for (a cleaner way with less code in my opinion).  My first code example is the way you asked for.  When I provide answers, I try to answer the question asked and then show a better answer that solves the problem if I see one.

Comment: it's not a different way because it sets the value without calling the setter logic which is what I needed and asked for, sorry I can't accept it like that

Comment: @jfriend00: just remove your proposal of setting default without calling setter :-) Yet, I like your answer as it is and I would have accepted it...

Comment: @kofifus - Then use my first code example.   You showed a simple static default value.  Not sure why that has to go through a setter.   You didn't show ANY complexity that requires a setter so I offered you a simpler option that doesn't need to use the setter.

Comment: because it was making a simple example of a much more complicated scenario

Comment: @kofifus - Well you didn't say that in your question.  Sorry, I tried to offer an additional option.  I will preface it with some comments.

Comment: @kofifus - I added some additional language before the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize it after object creation.

```
var o = {
  set p(val) {
    // setting logic
    alert(val);
    this.pval = val;
  },
  get p() {
    return this.pval;
  }
}
// initialize value after object creation
o.p = 10


alert(o.p);
```

Using a getter for variable initialization will execute in every get, which is inefficient.

Comment: This looks like commentary on the question, not an answer